# How to stop Android Studio suggesting "Insert App Indexing" quick fix?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-indexing

Android Studio keeps suggesting me to add App Indexing code.
Worse that it shows quick fix icon always when cursor is in line where there are no other problems.

Quick fixes become less useful because of need to care if it will not "fix" App Indexing problem.
Second - it's annoying and distract from real issues.

How to disable this "brilliant" feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brilliant indeed, took me an hour to undo the changes it caused and to turn it off for good.

**File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Firebase App Indexing -> uncheck.**

Restart Android Studio and it will be gone.

Note that this will remove the plugin, don't know if there is a way to just disable the quickfix suggestion.

Comment: i added small edit founded following Your track. thank You

Comment: As of 2018, this no longer works. I've had this plugin already disabled but the warnings were still there. Unchecking **Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Android -> Lint -> Usability -> Missing support for Firebase App Indexing** worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

If you need Firebase plugin enabled. Uncheck this function: **File->Settings->Editor->Intentions->"Android"\"Insert App Indexing API Code"**. This disables only annoing quickfix suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but for anyone who's still struggling with this, you can hide the warning by adding `tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"` attribute to the `application` tag.